# Creating a ZipFile from byte[] no longer available?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

There used to be a convenient static method in previous version of Ionic.Zip.Reduced that allowed to create a ZIP file from a byte array:

```
public static ZipFile Read(byte[] buffer)
```

My code looked something like this:

```
byte[] data = GetMyData();
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(data);
```

However, this method is no longer available in the most recent version. Why is that?

I came up with the following code which I believe is the equivalent:

```
byte[] data = GetMyData();
return ZipFile.Read(new MemoryStream(data));
```

Is the new code equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

'Why' is more a question for the DotNetZip team. I have a few ideas, though.

1. **Best practice for naming methods:** If you consider the name of the method, it doesn't make sense to Read an array.
2. **Memory utilization**: They are probably assuming that their users were already using a MemoryStream to generate the byte[] value and this new method prevents the double entry in memory.